# ASPNET : Use the label inside the link with database

Tags: asp.net, href

I have a link like this: `<a href ="xxx/category.html">`

How can I add from `xxx` with database?

I have tried like this:

```
<a href="<asp:Label ID="lblCatAdSeo" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>/<%#Eval("Category")%>.html">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution might be defining a code-behind method for this:

```
<a href='<%# GetFullUrl((string)Eval("Category")) %>'>
```

And in code-behind define it like this:

```
protected string GetFullUrl(string categoryName)
{
    // derive the full url
    return url;
}
```

If you are getting relevant url parts elsewhere, say during the `Page_Load`, you can simply store this info in some private field, and use it lately in this method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a databound control, it should be along the lines of:

```
<a href='<% Eval("xxx")/category'>...
```

Note the single vs. double quotes.

You can also mask the link if you're in a hyperlink column...you may be using the wrong type of control for what you need...